# Continuously getting content from table database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql

I have a code [here](https://gist.github.com/kejiro/bb8c7da5ee36a8bc447c0104208f5902#file-producerclear2-java-L66):

```
package testcode;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;


public class ProducerClear2 {

    public static String vardbserver;
    public static String vardbuser;
    public static String vardbpassword;
    public static String vardbname;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        vardbserver = "TestDBtoMQ";
        vardbuser = "postgresql";
        vardbpassword = "admin";

        ConnectionFactory factory = null;
        javax.jms.Connection connection = null;
        Session session = null;
        Destination destination = null;
        MessageProducer producer = null;
        try {
            factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
            connection = factory.createConnection();
            connection.start();
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            destination = session.createQueue("TestQueue");
            producer = session.createProducer(destination);

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            System.out.println("----------------------------");

            try (Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/" + vardbserver, vardbuser, vardbpassword);
                 PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MESSAGES where xmin::varchar::bigint > ? and xmin::varchar::bigint < ? ");
                 PreparedStatement max = c.prepareStatement("select max(xmin::varchar::bigint) as txid from messages")
            ) {
                c.setAutoCommit(false);

                Long previousTxId = 0L;
                Long nextTxId = 0L;

                while (true) {
                    stmt.clearParameters();

                    try (ResultSet rs = max.executeQuery()) {
                        if (rs.next()) {
                            nextTxId = rs.getLong(1);
                        }
                    }

                    stmt.setLong(1, previousTxId);
                    stmt.setLong(2, nextTxId + 1);
                    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            String message = rs.getString("MESSAGE");
                            System.out.println("Message = " + message);
                            TextMessage mssg = session.createTextMessage(message);
                            System.out.println("Sent: " + mssg.getText());
                            producer.send(mssg);
                        }
                        previousTxId = nextTxId;
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                try {
                    session.close();
                } catch (JMSException ex) {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (JMSException ex) {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("Message sent successfully");
    }
}
```

Basically, the app works to get contents inside a database's table and sent it to ActiveMQ. And when the table updated, it will sent the content that just updated (not sending the past that was sent). But this code only works on PostgreSQL

Then i'm planning to create an "if" function. So i can use another database to getting the data (Oracle and MySQL).

Is the xmin still works for Oracle and MySQL? So i just need to change the server URL? Or i need to change the code for Oracle and MySQL?

Comment: Step 1) spin up an VM. Step 2) install MySQL. Step 3) check the query.

Comment: `xmin::varchar::bigint` is not going to work in Oracle or in MySQL...

Comment: xmin isn't a simple ascending number. This will break.

Comment: @JohnHC so what should i use to make it work?

Comment: @RichardHuxton break what? im a beginner on coding, pls guide me if im wrong...

Comment: @NWD What is the datatype for `xmin`?

Comment: @JohnHC i didnt make the xmin column, is that it's function to creating a "virtual" column? Im trying to query the message column, that have a varchar as datatype...

Comment: If you're a "beginner on coding" why have you decided to start with this problem, one which requires an understanding of JMS and three different RDBMS products?

Comment: @APC Yes im just a student that try to get some reference here to answering my lecture task that he gave to me. Btw if u didnt want to help someone, so just leave and dont mind it. Not every people can explaining all the details why he/she asking... thankyou...

Comment: Okay, here's some help. I guess you didn't write the code in GitHub. The problem with that code is that it mixes generic message handling code with specific connection code. Your first step should be to break that code into two layers: message handling + database access (generic), PostgreSQL functionality (specific). Now you can see that you need to write further specific modules for MySQL, Oracle, whatever which you can inject into the generic layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply found the answer, using limit, save it's every limit row to a file and use a date for every daily file....

```
              if(vardbtype.equals("MYSQL")){
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    System.out.println("----------------------------");
                    int limitrowmysql = 0;
                    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
                    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:\\Users\\NN\\Documents\\Test\\RowMYSQL\\RowIDMYSQL_" + now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE) + ".txt");
                    if (Files.exists(path)) {
                        String latestRowIdFromFile  = Files.lines(path).max((e1, e2) -> {
                        if (((String)e1).isEmpty() || ((String)e2).isEmpty()) {
                            return -1;
                        }
                        return new Long(e1).compareTo(new Long(e2));
                        }).get(); // read latestRowId from file
                        if (latestRowIdFromFile != null && !latestRowIdFromFile.isEmpty()) {
                            limitrowmysql = Integer.valueOf(latestRowIdFromFile);
                        }
                    } else {
                        limitrowmysql = 0;
                    }
                    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+ vardbserver, vardbuser, vardbpassword);
                    while(true) {
                        Statement stmts = c.createStatement();
                        int countrowmysql = 0;
                        String sql = ("SELECT * FROM "+ vardbname +" LIMIT "+ limitrowmysql +", 18446744073709551615");
                        ResultSet rss = stmts.executeQuery(sql);
                        while(rss.next()) {
                            String  message = rss.getString("MESSAGE");
                            System.out.println("Message = " + message);
                            TextMessage mssg = session.createTextMessage(message);
                            System.out.println("Sent: " + mssg.getText());
                            producer.send(mssg);
                            countrowmysql = countrowmysql + 1;
                        }

                        rss.close();
                        stmts.close();
                        Thread.sleep(batchperiod2);

                        limitrowmysql = limitrowmysql + countrowmysql;
                        Files.write(path, ("\n" + limitrowmysql).getBytes()); // write latestRowId to file
                    }
                }
```