# Oracle's ROWID / ROWNUM in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, rowid

I'm trying to get the equivalent for this code on MySQL

```
try(Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:"+ vardbserver, vardbuser, vardbpassword);
      PreparedStatement stmts = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM "+ vardbname +" where ROWNUM > ? and ROWNUM < ? ");
      PreparedStatement max = c.prepareStatement("select max(ROWNUM) as txid from "+ vardbname)
      )
```

I've looking for the sample but i got a dead end.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I believe that this question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728413/equivalent-of-oracle-s-rowid-in-mysql

Comment: @Aaron im trying to get the data inside a column, but it'll continuously getting the data when the database updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tablename where ROWNUM > ? and ROWNUM < ?
> ```

`ROWNUM` is used to select a subset of rows, i.e. rows between the two values (exclusive). First row of the query is numbered 1, second row is 2, and so on.

MySQL supports the `LIMIT` syntax, where you instead specify how many rows you want, and which row to get first:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT offset, row_count
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT row_count OFFSET offset
```

An offset of 0 returns the first row.

So, you can calculate the two values for MySQL from the two values you had in Oracle. I'll leave that calculation up to you.

> ```
> select max(ROWNUM) as txid from tablename
> ```

Well, I've never seen this one before, but if the query returned 10 rows, the max `ROWNUM` would be 10, so it is essentially the same as:

```
select count(*) as txid from tablename
```

Comment: basically im trying to get the data inside a column, but it'll continuously getting the data when the database updated... i got the PostgreQSL code, and trying to get it on Oracle and MySQL... Here's the link https://gist.github.com/kejiro/bb8c7da5ee36a8bc447c0104208f5902#file-producerclear2-java-L66

Comment: WOAH!!! That's a totally different thing. `xmin` (PostgreSQL) and `rownum` (Oracle) have nothing in common. Your question is not even about PostgreSQL. If you have a question about performing those PostgreSQL queries on Oracle and MySQL, you should ask *that* (as a new question), though I suspect that it cannot be done. I have answered *this* question.

Comment: WEW... I've questioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535659/continuously-getting-content-from-table-database and didn't got the answer, so i tried to get the oracle's and asking the mysql's... :|